# Moving and collecting a file using php to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssis

Due to failings within SSIS and losing patience I thought of using php as a go between to help move and retrieve files from the AMAZON S3 bucket.

Theres an access issue that we cant seem to get round

Steps so far

WE use IIS 
The Amazon PHP SDK was downloaded
user `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpaws` a `index.php` file was created

the code

```
/error_reporting(E_ERROR);
require './aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = 'BUCKET';
$keyname = 'RKPHPTest.txt';
$filepath = './RKPHPTest.txt';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'NAME',
    'secret' => 'NAME',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'ssl.certificate_authority' => 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpaws\cacert.pem'
));

try {

    // Download data.
    $result = $s3->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => "NAME.txt"
    ));

    // Print the object.
    echo $result;
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}

echo "<br><br>";

try {

    // Upload data.
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $keyname,
        'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
        'ACL'    => 'public-read'
    ));

    // Print the URL to the object.
    echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Then when the API is ran we get on both post and get error msg

> Error executing "GetObject" AWS HTTP error: Client error: 403
>   AccessDenied (client): Access Denied - AccessDeniedAccess

the permissions on account are as follows:

```
{ 
  "Statement": [ 
    { 
      "Effect": "Allow", 
      "Action": "s3:*", 
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET*" 
    }, 
    { 
      "Effect": "Allow", 
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets", 
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*" 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

Which means we can do all commands any suggestions on how to get around this error would be great?

Many thanks

Robert

---

TO be clear

This is the full permissions listed

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET"
    }
  ]
}ShowPolicy{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "importexport:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why is $bucket = 'BUCKET'? Shouldn't it be 'gf-redshift-upload-dev'?

Comment: Apologies simply missed putting the arn as BUCKET not to display what it actually was.

Comment: Add "Version":"2012-10-17" to your policy, and change "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET*" to "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/*" then retry. You may also want to use the IAM policy simulator or install the awscli and test basic S3 commands while you debug your policy.